# How to disable the cut copy paste option in Edit Text in HTC device in OS 2.x

Tags: android, android-layout

In HTC device with OS 2.x we want to disable the cut copy paste option on the edit text.
How can we disable this?

Help Appreciated.

Thanks!
Bhushan

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

```
edtUserName.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```